# How to make my page automatically scroll up an down

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, scroll

I'm trying to make a team-wall to display every employee's schedule. The form is some kind of table. There are too many elements to be shown, so the page needs to automatically scroll down and up in a loop. I tried multiple scripts but somehow they didn't work.
I hope you are able to help me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <title>Projekt-Liste</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/normalize.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/layout.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/projekte.css" />




    </head>

        <div class="top_leiste" id="top_leiste_fix">
            <img class="logo" id="westnetz" src="bilder/westnetz.png"><div id="zahl">Lehrjahr 2017</div><!--img class="logo" id="eon" src="bilder/eon.png"-->
            <div class="datum_zeile">
                <div class="azubi_bild"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle;"></div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">06.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum"> 
                        <div class="date">07.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">08.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">09.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">10.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum_we"> 
                        <div class="date">11/12.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">13.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">14.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">15.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">16.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">17.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum_we">
                        <div class="date">18/19.</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    <body>  

                                                                                                                                <!--    Listen-Ansicht  -->

    <div id="page">
        <div class="top_leiste">
            <img class="logo" src="bilder/westnetz.png">Lehrjahr 2017<img class="logo" src="bilder/eon.png">
        </div>
        <div id="main">

        <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Datumsleiste--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                        <div class="datum_zeile">
                <div class="azubi_bild"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle;"></div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">06.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum"> 
                        <div class="date">07.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">08.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">09.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">10.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum_we"> 
                        <div class="date">11/12.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">13.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">14.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">15.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">16.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum">
                        <div class="date">17.01.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="datum_we">
                        <div class="date">18/19.</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 0----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/alnaeb.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Mostafa</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                        Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 1----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/binz.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Sharon</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 2----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/borkowski.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Saskia</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 3----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/bukaev.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Ramil</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 4----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/christoffels.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Marvin</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi">
                            Jufi
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                    <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                    <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi">
                            Jufi
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                    <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                    <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Jufi"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 5----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/giesen.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Micha</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 6----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/goetz.jpg""></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Tobias</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 7----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/mertens.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Nico</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 8----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/s.muench.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">Sabrina</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV">
                            PDV
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino">
                            Aduino Tür
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                    <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV">
                            PDV
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino">
                            Aduino Tür
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PDV"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Aduino"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Azubi 12---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

                    <div class="azubi_zeile">
                <div img src="/bilder/Profilbild.png" class="azubi_bild"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="bilder/Lj2017/van_der_beek.jpg"></div>
                <div class="azubi_name" style="vertical-align: middle">David</div>
                <div class= "azubi_wochen">
                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz">
                            Betriebseinsatz
                        </div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV">
                            Prüfungsvorb.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="Einsatz"></div>
                        <div class="azubi_projekt" id="PV"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule">Schule</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag">
                        <div class="azubi_schule"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="azubi_tag_we"> 
                        <div class="azubi_projekt">

                        </div>
                    </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]`snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried now. sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function on setInterval and in that function use the code like this

```
 setInterval(function(){
    scrollUpandDown();

},5000);
function scrollUpandDown(){
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function(event){
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > lastScrollTop){
         // downscroll code
      } else {
        // upscroll code
      }
      lastScrollTop = st;
   });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i need to cinfigure it for my containers i think... but how...

Comment: you can assign Id to them

Answer (score 0):

As Amit said - use setInterval:

```
var time= 5000;
var pause = 1000;
setInterval(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, time);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, time);

}, time + time + pause);
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jco3fz2q/ (starts after 11 secs)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i need to cinfigure it for my containers i think... but how...

Comment: It should work. Added your html to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jco3fz2q/1/ But you have a <div> container above the <body> tag. Maybe this is messing things up.Removed it in the fiddle

Comment: First: Thank you very much for your help... it seems to work in jsfiddle. But I have one question:
Did you delete the <body>-Tag? This would cause some problems for me if I would try to use it...

Comment: And I have a second question:
I need jquery, right? I added it by downloading it, putting it in the same folder than my php-files. Then I used the <script>-tag in the head to include jquery 3.4.1 and my "script.js" where i put the javascript code.. but somehoq it doesn't work..

Comment: It just doesn't scroll.. even though the same code does in jsfiddle.. Im so confused